# How can I change and remove some values from the output of the flatten layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I used a VGGNet for image processing and I want to calculate the mean of the flatten layer and then I want to remove the values that have a difference of less than 1 from the mean value. But I can not and encunter with error.

> re = delete(tf.where(flatten > flattenmean+0.01 )) NameError: name 'delete' is not defined

Code:

```py
def configInitialModel(input):
#    conv=Conv2D(8, 3, 3, border_mode='same',
#                     input_shape=input_shape, activation='relu')(input)
#    conv=Conv2D(8, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu')(conv)
#    conv=MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv)
#
    conv=Conv2D(16, 3, 3, border_mode='same',
                     input_shape=input_shape, activation='relu')(input)
    conv=Conv2D(16, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu')(conv)
    conv=MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv)
    conv=Conv2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same',
                     input_shape=input_shape, activation='relu')(conv)
    conv=Conv2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu')(conv)
    conv=MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv)
    conv=Conv2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same',
                     input_shape=input_shape, activation='relu')(conv)
    conv=Conv2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu')(conv)
    conv=MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv)
    conv=Conv2D(128, 3, 3, border_mode='same',
                     input_shape=input_shape, activation='relu')(conv)
    conv=Conv2D(128, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu')(conv)
    conv=MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv)
    conv=Conv2D(256, 3, 3, border_mode='same',
                     input_shape=input_shape, activation='relu')(conv)
    conv=Conv2D(256, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation= 'relu')(conv)   # Custom Activation
    conv=MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv)
    # conv=Activation('sigmoid')(conv)
   
    flatten= Flatten()(conv)
    ###     $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
    flattenmean = tf.reduce_mean(flatten)
    re = delete(tf.where(flatten > flattenmean+0.01 ))
#       
    dense=Dense(256, activation='relu')(flatten)
    dense=Dropout(0.5)(dense)
    dense= Dense(256, activation='relu')(dense)
    dense=Dropout(0.5)(dense)
    dense=Dense(1)(dense)
    output=Activation('sigmoid')(dense)
    
      
    return output
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really want to "delete" the values. Maybe set them to 0?

```
tf.where(condition, 0)
```

Comment: I want to remove and delete the values but I can not. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Can you elaborate your use case? I have a hard time trying to visualize what you're trying to accomplish. VGG works on images in general, and therefore you don't really delete pixels that you don't want.